# CodeIgniter Dynamic DB connection via URL

Tags: php, codeigniter

I need to connect to a DB that's name will be entered in the URL.
For Example the URL will be

`http://my_url.com/comp/login`

So the DB I need to connect to is 'comp'.

Is there a way to do this without defining each database in the database.php config file?

something like

```
define('COMP', $this -> uri -> segment(1));
```

and then

```
'database' => 'tm_'.COMP,
```

The above gives me an error about the $this, so I am not completely sure where I can define the COMP variable where the database config file can read it.

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Was missing this part :

```
$CI =& get_instance();
```

and updated the

```
define('COMP', $this -> uri -> segment(1));
```

to

```
define('COMP', $CI -> uri -> segment(1));
```

is working now